# Wordpress different database Error establishing a database connection

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get data from different mysql database(different server) in my wordpress site, but having the Error establishing database connection.

$seconddb= new wpdb('DB_USER','DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_NAME', 'DB_HOST');

Its working perfectly in local development, but in hosting site provides the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission for you user for this database.
Or maybe wrong db host , can you sent DB_HOST ?

Comment: Using the same query in local-get the results. But in server getting error. All the credential are right. By the way, the second db is not a wordpress db.

Comment: Ohh bro you can connect only wp_db couse in wp-db has certain tables and structure

Comment: I didnt reach any source regarding this after lots of search..By the way, thanks for your information.